# Trying to repair SQL Server 12 Database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Have the following code in Transact SQL to try and repair a database

```
DBCC CHECKDB     
   DBCC CHECKDB     
   [  Sellmdat2ksql | 5 
    [ , NOINDEX     
    | , { REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS | REPAIR_FAST | REPAIR_REBUILD } ]    
     ) ]    
 GO
```

I get the following error, Not familiar with Transact sql

Incorrect syntax near ' (Sellmdat2ksql | 5 
        [, NOINDEX
        [, { REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS | REPAIR_FAST | REPAIR_REBUILD } '.

Comment: Your syntax is wrong in so many places. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkdb-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Looks like you just copy/pasted the syntax grammar.  You need to read about which options you need to use and how to set those parameters.

Comment: Are you sure you should be the one repairing the database? I mean this is not the kind of thing you typically have somebody do that isn't pretty comfortable with this. But perhaps you are an accidental dba and have choice. There are several steps that need to happen PRIOR to repairing the database.

Comment: It's usually better to restore from backup than use the REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS option.

Comment: I am not a DBA, I'm a contract programmer that has a copy of a corrupted data base in my sand box.  It is not the working database but the one I use to write code against.  Was hoping I could do a quick repair so that I have some data to work with.  So any help with the syntax would be greatly appreciated

Comment: you may get more help with db repair on [dba stack exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

```
 ALTER DATABASE Sellmdat2ksql
 SET SINGLE_USER;

 DBCC CHECKDB ('Sellmdat2ksql ', REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS);

 ALTER DATABASE Sellmdat2ksql
 SET MULTI_USER;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, We will need to set the database into single user mode, run the repair and then set the database back into multi user mode.

```
ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorks2008R2 SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
DBCC CHECKDB ('Sellmdat2ksql', REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS);
ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorks2008R2 SET MULTI_USER;
```

If its not worked, you can also use software recovery tool As I stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59054812/2118383)

You can use the tool [SQL Database Recovery Tool Repairs](https://www.stellarinfo.com/sql-recovery.php), Which will be used to repair the corrupted database.,